# Creating an image from a custom field

Tags: php, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, html

I'm working on the theme creation in WordPress.  When I try to customize hero image(using advance custom plugin) in my theme it doesn't appears and i gave image path in css file. Here some code of html and css.

HTML

```
<?php 
$hero = get_field('hero'); ?>
<div id="home-cover" class="bg-parallax animated fadeIn">
```

CSS

```
#home-cover {
    height: 100%;
   background-image: url(<?php echo $image['url']; ?>);
}
```

Comment: Where is that CSS code being generated? You can't use PHP inside `.css` files

Comment: Even if CSS would allow php (which it doesn't) your ACF field is likely returning an array (which is default).

Comment: when i give image path in .html file it mess up with my sections and  shows overlapping

Comment: i change image array to image url in ACF

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

Add the image path in PHP using an inline style, instead of in your CSS.

```
<div 
    style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image['url']; ?>);" 
    id="home-cover" 
    class="bg-parallax animated fadeIn"
> // close div
```

Comment: i tried your code but it doesn't work

Comment: Inspect the page and see what the value of background-image is?  Is it empty, array?

Comment: when i define image url in inline style with php code the whole theme disappear

Comment: means you have an error in your PHP, turn on debug and see what it says

Comment: thanks man its done